# react error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" under the map iteration

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to move keys and values in propsValue to Users using immer.

Furthermore, there are 2 buttons.

"convert them" moves propsValue into a new Array.

"print all" prints all key and value of the new Array.

In my theory, it should be worked perfectly and keys and values in propsValue were moved into

users.

However, it prints "Expected an assignment or function call ..." when the button clicked.

please share your kind advice to solve this problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useImmer } from "use-immer";
const UserImmer = () => {
  const propsValue = [
    {
      value: "Name", key:"first_name"
    },
    {
      value: "last Name", key:"last_name"
    },
    {
      value: "E mail", key:"e_mail"
    },
    {
      value: "Address", key: "address"
    }
  ]

  const [user, setUser] = useImmer({
    name: '',
    key: '',
  })
  const [users, setUsers] = useImmer([])

  const onbuttonChange = () => {
    //iteration begins
    propsValue.map(data =>  (
       //moves propsValue key, value into user
      setUser(draftState => {
        draftState.name =  data.name,
        draftState.key = data.key
      }),
      //push new array key and value into Users
      setUsers(draftState => {
        draftState.push(user);
      }),
      //initialize the array 
      setUser(draftState => {
        draftState.name = "",
        draftState.key = ""
      })
    ) )
    
    
  }
  const onClickUser = () => {
    users.map(temp => console.log(temp.name, " : " , temp.key));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      
      <button onClick={onClickUser}>print All</button>
      <button onClick={onbuttonChange}>Convert them</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default UserImmer;
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution. modified some comma and semi-colon

```
  propsValue.map(data =>  (
       //moves propsValue key, value into user    
        setUser(draft => {
            draft.name =  data.name;
            draft.key = data.key;
          }),
          setUsers(draft => {
            draft.push(user);
          }),
          setUser(draft => {
            draft.name ="";
            draft.key = "";
          })
    ) )
```